Why does the profiler says that my component gets re-render even though I memoized it?
In the following code, which is for learning purposes, when I click on "I am App's BTN" (which is App's button) only, and out of context, essentially on top of all other things, in the case of the RenderList component, the React profiler extension indicates that it re-renders due to a props changed: {children} while I though it should not re-render like Counter component. I also tried to memoize the children itself, but it still gives me the same reason. I'm seeking an answer solely for understanding and learning purposes.
import { useContext } from "react";
import { memo } from "react";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { Children } from "react";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { createContext } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const TestContext = createContext();

function TestProvider({ children }) {
  const [change, setChange] = useState(10);
  const value = useMemo(() => {
    return { change, setChange };
  }, [change]);

  return <TestContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</TestContext.Provider>;
}

function App() {
  const [some, setSome] = useState(true);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setSome(false)}>iam App's BTN !</button>
      <TestProvider>
        <Counter />
        <RenderList>
          <MamaMia />
        </RenderList>
      </TestProvider>
    </>
  );
}

const Counter = memo(function Counter() {
  const { setChange } = useContext(TestContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setChange((prev) => prev + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
});

const RenderList = memo(function RenderList({ children }) {
  const { change } = useContext(TestContext);

  const memoizedChildren = useMemo(() => {
    return <Fragment>{children}</Fragment>;
  }, [children]);
  return (
    <div>
      {memoizedChildren}
      <p>{change}</p>
    </div>
  );
});

const MamaMia = memo(function MamaMia() {
  return <p>hello mama mia !</p>;
});

export default App;


To understand this we have to understand little bit how JSX works.
<MamaMia /> this is equivalent to a call to the method React.createElement.
What is to be understood is who makes that call -> App component and not RenderList.
If App makes that call, and it's result is not cached (eg: with the help of useMemo) the resultant object will be different every time. And that is what the profiler means when it says the children have changed. Because children is never the same object.
React.memo works as it should, and hence  a log inside MamaMia will not run twice because it did not re-render.
Counter does not rerender because it has no such children and is also memoized.
RenderList rerenders because its children changed, as we saw above.
If we memoize the result of the above mentioned React.createElement call, we will not have this issue anymore.
function App() {
  const [some, setSome] = useState(true);

  const MamaMiaComp = useMemo(() => {
    return <MamaMia />;
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setSome((x) => !x)}>iam App's BTN !</button>
      <TestProvider>
        <Counter />
        <RenderList>{MamaMiaComp}</RenderList>
      </TestProvider>
    </>
  );
}

Log on 1 click before:

Log on 1 click after:

Here is a demo. Comment/Uncomment the patch I have done to see the difference.

Note: All the context here is red herring, and this will have the same effect without the context too.

thanks alot i think i get it know , so because we already know {}==={} =>false in js  so each re-render causes a new object of that component to be made , so even there is no diffrent between them but because the object is refrence type so the address of each is diffrent in memory so it consider it a new object

Yes, two object variables can never be same in JS unless they point to the same object. That is a separate topic in itself
